# How best should I keep track of a timer between page requests?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm writing a web app in PHP that lets users take mock exams (multiple choice questions).

The exams are timed, for instance 30 minutes. I'm not sure what the best approach to keep track of how long the user has left to complete their exam is. Each question is pulled from a MySQL database and served to the user as a new page.

Should I start a timer on the first page with Javascript (e.g. setInterval) and then POST that to the server whenever a question is submitted before retrieving the next page?  Is there a more elegant or efficient way to do it?

Comment: Storing the start-time in a session seems the most secure way.

Comment: The simplest way (not necessarily the most secure) would be to just store the start-time in a cookie.  That start time value will then be available on each subsequent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table that stores the test to user association and put a time in there when the test is no longer valid. This will permit to to query and find out what students have what time remaining, as well as lock out people from re-attempting the test if this is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they have 30minutes for the whole test and no breaks i would store a timestamp when they click start.

```
$_SESSION['start_time'] = time(true);
```

You could then either poll via ajax that time when they are on the page, or you could set javascript variable that runs a countdown via `setInterval()`

```
<script>
var elapsedTime = <?=time(true) - $_SESSION['start_time'] ?>`;
var timer = setTimeout(function () {
   if (elapsedTime > 30 * 6) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      alert('game over');
   }
   elapsedTime += 1;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Clearing cookies is not hard. Wouldn't that reset the timer?

Comment: @tadman - they could store progress in the session as well then if they cleared the session cookie they would clear all of their progress

Comment: BTW, `time()` takes no arguments - you can skip the `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the start time in a cookie with expiry time set to `30*60 secs`.

See [php.net](http://php.net/setcookie)